# bash change directory with "shortcuts"

Tags: bash, cd

On my windows computer I use JPSofts "Take Command" a.k.a. TCMD as command.com or shell replacement.

One tcmd feature I really miss when working with bash on Linux/Os X, is the **extended directory search** that uses a database of directories (JPSTREE.IDX) to allow direct access to a deeply nested directory by just typing e.g.:

*cd <nested-dir-name>*

then the shell changes directories to that path. 
Natural there are ways to add/remove entries from the dir-search-DB.

Is there a similar tool for bash?

Comment: Take a look at variable $CDPATH in bash's manpage.

Comment: @Cyrus: I missed $CDPATH!  .. only (slight) downside is the need for manual editing of the list ... If you'll convert your comment to an answer I'll gladly accept it!